# map function to columns of list iterator

Tags: python, csv, iterator

Imagine I'm reading in a csv file of numbers that looks like this:

```
1,6.2,10
5.4,5,11
17,1.5,5
...
```

And it's really really long.

I'm going to iterate through this file with a csv reader like this:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader('numbers.csv')
```

Now assume I have some function that can take an iterator like max:

```
max((float(rec[0]) for rec in reader))
```

This finds the max of the first column and doesn't need to read the whole file into memory.

But what if I want to run max on each column of the csv file, still without reading the whole file into memory?

If max were rewritten like this:

```
def max(iterator):
    themax = float('-inf')
    for i in iterator:
        themax = i if i > themax else themax
        yield
    yield themax
```

I could then do some fancy work (and have) to make this happen.

But what if I constrain the problem and don't allow max to be rewritten? Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable with a more functional approach you can use functools.reduce to iterate through the file, pulling only two rows into memory at once, and accumulating the column-maximums as it goes.

```
import csv
from functools import reduce

def column_max(row1, row2):
    # zip contiguous rows and apply max to each of the column pairs
    return [max(float(c1), float(c2)) for (c1, c2) in zip(row1, row2)]

reader = csv.reader('numbers.csv')
# calling `next` on reader advances its state by one row
first_row = next(reader)
column_maxes = reduce(column_max, reader, first_row)
#
#
# another way to write this code is to unpack the reduction into explicit iteration
column_maxes = next(reader) # advances `reader` to its second row
for row in reader:
    column_maxes = [max(float(c1), float(c2)) for (c1, c2) in zip(column_maxes, row)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just move away from using a function which you pass the iterator but instead iterate on your own over the reader:

```
maxes = []
for row in reader:
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if i > len(maxes):
            maxes.append(row[i])
        else:
            maxes[i] = max(maxes[i], row[i])
```

At the end, you will have the list `maxes` which will contain each maximum value, without having the whole file in memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
def col_max(x0,x1):
    """x0 is a list of the accumulated maxes so far,
    x1 is a line from the file."""
    return [max(a,b) for a,b in zip(x0,x1)]
```

Now functools.reduce(col_max,reader,initializer) will return just what you want.  You will have to supply initializer as a list of -inf's of the correct length.